# Any way to include flatpak .desktop files to the ones scanned by the Applications menu?

Tags: release-loki, app-shortcuts

I have a couple of apps installed via flatpak but their `.desktop` app launchers' location isn't included to be scanned and added to the Applications menu.

Is there any way to include them to the path being scanned instead of manually copying the app launchers to `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: For now can you symlink?

Comment: This might be something like a patch for a Ubuntu/elementary flatpak installer package

Answer (score 2):

I haven't confirmed this, but elementary OS probably adheres to the standards defined by Freedesktop.org.  If this is the case, you can append your special path to one of the environment variables in the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/). The environment variable you want to append is probably [$XDG_DATA_DIRS](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html).  Use a colon ':' to separate paths in the variable.

I'm not sure how to force a refresh after this.  Maybe try a reboot, or google for an answer.

Comment: You're correct, the applications-menu app looks in XDG [standard directories for application files](https://github.com/elementary/applications-menu/blob/a824105bdd02bdadb8e4ae496b99589812ac992a/lib/synapse-core/desktop-file-service.vala#L379). After installing Blender, a reboot resolved this issue for me.